# Blank spaces between thumbs on gallery page

Tags: css, gallery

I am having a strange blank spaces between thumbs on my gallery page.
I don't know why this happens. I tried to change css code but without success.
Previously everything was alright.

Link is here: http://www.chriskalmar.com/themes/advisory/gallery.html

If someone of you guys know what can cause such a behaviour.

Comment: Inspect fourth image holder... You have one HTML error there, check href attribute...

Comment: I don't see any error. if you see better please

Answer (score 0):

Adding this rule to remove the unwanted margin between thumbs:

```
#thumbs li {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: i'd add !important to that

Comment: I went to the very end of main.css and pasted it and it works. please make sure you do it like that.

Comment: Thank you Heidar. I did exactly like that and this combine all images together but the main problem (the big gap at 4,7,8 image placehoder) still exist.